# How to send email html template in SIDDHI IO EMAIL?

Tags: wso2, html-email, siddhi

I am using siddhi with WSO2.
 In siddhi email there is an option that says that is posible to send html. According to this I suppose there is a way to send template html. I want these because I need a more frindly email than just the event in plain txt.
Or something to change the body of the email.

```
@source(type='email', @map(type='xml'), username='receiver.account', password='account.password',content.type='text/html,)
    define stream inputStream (name string, age int, country string);
```

Up to now I haven't found a way to add the html or where to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send HTML email instead of `@map(type='xml')` use

```
@map(type = 'text', @payload("""
<html>
<body>
Hi {{name}} <br/>
Good luck with your email :) 
</body>
</html>
"""))
```

with proper email tempate.